# Registry Key Permissions Broken - How to Recover Access

Tags: permissions, windows-registry, dropbox, svn

I was recently looking for a solution to stop Dropbox from fighting with Svn for priority over the `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` in the system registry.

[One solution](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox/Shell-Overlay-Icons/idi-p/111622/page/4#comments) was to set the permissions on the key to deny write access.  However it seems I've made a grave error and have been a bit over zealous with revoking these permissions.

Now I just get errors when trying to look at the permissions let alone update them.  I've tried running RegEdit as Administrator but that still doesn't allow me to view or change the key.  I just keep getting the message:

> Error Opening Key
>
> ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers cannot be opened.  An
>   error is preventing this key from being opened.  Details: Access is
>   denied.

If I run `RegEdit` as adminstrator I still cannot view the contents.  If I right-click and select `Permissions` I get a warning message saying:

> Windows Security
>
> You do not have permissions to view the current permission settings
>   for ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers, but you can make permission changes.

Which seems a little odd.

Is there any way I can recover from this situation or is this now a lost cause?

Comment: Does opening the registry as the SYSTEM user help? See this answer [Unable to delete registry key](//superuser.com/a/454557)

Comment: YES!!  David, post your comment as an answer so I can give you some love!  Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to delete registry key](https://superuser.com/questions/454551/unable-to-delete-registry-key)

Comment: The proper thing for me to do is close this question as a duplicate of the other one - not try and gain rep. The proper thing for you to do is upvote the answer to that other question.

Comment: True, but to be fair I would never have found that answer given my situation and googling hadn't turned that up.